# How can I prevent reordering of the last cell in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to prevent the last cell in a collection view from being reordered. Essentially I want an "add item" cell to always be the last cell in the collection.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am using [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout) to reorder my cells using the longPress gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple way to do it.

[The details of how to do so are here.](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial#Implementing_a_Supplementary_View)

This tutorial shows how to set up supplementary views (headers or footers) in a UICollectionView. I just added my labels and buttons to my custom supplementary view and voila!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ... this helps me ...

```
          - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
             {
              return [array count]+1;
              }



          - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
               {
               if (indexPath.row == ([array count]+1)) {
                    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
                    headerLabel.text = @"your text";
                    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(110.0, 11.0, 100.0, 20.0);
                    [cell addSubview:headerLabel];
                    }
                 else
                   {
                   }
               }
```

I hope this will help you.

happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It looks to me like you are adding a label to the bottom of the last cell. What happens when you try to reorganize that cell you attached the headerLabel too? Does it not get reordered along with the cell?